# Manipulating <p> text depending on country

Tags: jquery, geolocation

I want to change a

text depending on a country, here's my code which does not work:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    country = geoplugin_countryName();
    if (country === "Russia") {
        $("p").text("blabla")   
    });
```

EDIT: edited to $("p").text("blabla"). Now i get `Uncaught ReferenceError: geoplugin_countryName is not defined`

any clues? :)

Comment: what is geoplugin_countryName()?

Comment: its javascript function, based on this plugin: http://www.geoplugin.com/webservices/javascript

Comment: did you refer that js in your code?

Comment: not specifically, but the code is in external "jquery.js" file

Answer (score 0):

it should be

```
$("p").text("blabla");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

```
$("p").html("blabla");
```

Answer (score -1):

use to append html as:

```
$("p").html("blabla");
```

and compare as

```
$("p").html() === "blabla"
```